# CSS layout best practice

Tags: css, layout, html

I am unsure what the best combination of CSS rules and HTML elemtents is to achieve this layout:

[example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ykP.png)

(Apologies for the image, it was the best way I could think of to express what I had in mind)

It is essentially a table with 2 rows and 4 columns, but I don't want to use tables.

I'm fairly confident I could hack something together that would do this but it wouldn't be elegant or optimal and I want to know the cleanest way of doing it.

Let me know if this is not clear. Thanks

Comment: feel free using float and line-height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NwHM7/28/

Comment: Thanks everyone. Some really useful & insightful answers. Yuri's just fitted my needs well. I think a grid layout like 960.gs or 1200px might have been overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/semencov/P8B4R/

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what's your target audicence, consider using [1200px.com](http://1200px.com/).

In case you already have your template, I made you this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLXby/6/). You can start from there :)

http://jsfiddle.net/aLXby/6/

Answer (score 1):

For simple layout, float all the containers ("columns") left and make sure to [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) the parent container of those columns:

```
<section class="clearfix">
    <figure>
        <img src="img1.jpg">
        <figcaption>Text here</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="img2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Text here</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="img3.jpg">
        <figcaption>Text here</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="img4.jpg">
        <figcaption>Text here</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Your CSS might be:

```
(clearfix as described on linked page)

figure {
    float: left;
}
```

For more control and structure, try a grid system, like [960.gs](http://960.gs).

This example is assuming that your images have captions, and the [HTML5 figure tag and figcaption tags](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) are well-suited for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to keep your HTML semantic. So there's no "HTML best suited for this layout" but rather HTML best suited for that content. In this case it's what Matt suggests (`figure` and `figcaption`). I would probably use a list (`ul` with `li`) rather than section though.

Regarding the styling, there are numerous ways to achieve that layout. Depending on your specific needs (are the images equal height? equal width? what about the captions? one line? several lines? etc) you might get by using floats, you could also use `display: inline-block` and if you really want to replicate a table you can use `display: table/table-row/table-cell`.

Edit: I'd argue that using a grid system for this is like using an MVC framework to display an animated gif. All grid systems I've seen require the user to add quite a load of `div`s and classes that ruin your markup.